# Can you loop through an array of strings and match their value to keys in object dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, for-loop

For example, I want the entered string of "cab" to return "Clown Ace Boss".

```
    var wiseBacronyms = function(initialInput) {
      initialInput = initialInput.toLowerCase();
      var dictionary = {"a":"Ace","b":"Boss","c":"Clown"};
      var letterArray = initialInput.split('');
      var result = [];

      for (var index = 0; index < letterArray.length; index++) {
        result.push(dictionary[index]);
      };
      return result.join('');
    };
```

Comment: var dictionary = {"a":"Ace","b":Boss,"c":"Clown"}; is incorrect, should be in array literal...

Comment: Boss should be "Boss", but I'm still getting an error

Comment: @C-linkNepal no, it's fine like that, the problem is that it should look like `result.push(dictionary[letterArray[index]]);`

Comment: @C-linkNepal: Think again. It *is* an object literal, everything is fine with that.

Comment: *"Can you loop through an array of strings and match their value to keys in object dictionary?"* Yes you can. What is the problem with the solution you have? *"but I'm still getting an error"* If you share it with us, maybe we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pull the `index` from the dictionary, but the `letterArray[index]`.

```
function wiseBacronyms(initialInput) {
  initialInput = initialInput.toLowerCase();
  var dictionary = {"a":"Ace","b":"Boss","c":"Clown"};
  var letterArray = initialInput.split('');
  var result = [];

  for (var index = 0; index < letterArray.length; index++) {
    result.push(dictionary[letterArray[index]]);
  };
  return result.join(' '); // also I added a space here
}

wiseBacronyms("cab") // "Clown Ace Boss"
```

Comment: Of course this whole function could be shortened to `function wiseBacronyms(initialInput) {
  var dictionary = {"a":"Ace","b":"Boss","c":"Clown"};
  return initialInput.toLowerCase().split('').map(function(letter) { return dictionary[letter]; }).join(' ');
}`

Comment: oh, yeah! you are right, but still just index won't help think of value not key...

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the properties for each item in `letterArray` and add them to your `result` array, finally using `join(' ')` to make your string. Like so:

```
var wiseBacronyms = function(initialInput) {
    initialInput = initialInput.toLowerCase();
    var dictionary = {"a":"Ace","b":"Boss","c":"Clown"};
    var letterArray = initialInput.split('');
    var result = [];

    letterArray.forEach(function(l) {
        result.push(dictionary[l]);
    });

    return result.join(' ');
};
```